# JavaScript: Clear form data after submit to self on click

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Student newb here working to construct a history of my class assignments in a manner which is helpful to me for future reflection; Currently I'm doing a form assignment, which works but i'm trying to push it a touch to get the most out of the experience. My goal is that if i click the 'reset' button the form will clear regardless of if i've clicked the submit ('continue') button or not. Currently if i click the clear button before clicking the submit button, the form data will clear. But if i've clicked the continue (to submit the form to self and the form data is now sitting on in the url), the data will not clear.

this is my javascript function

```
<script>
/* JS to clear form */
function myFunction() { document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); }
</script>
```

this is the whole form part of the code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./itc216.php" method="get">
                    Name: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input ="text" name="userName" value="<?php echo $userName; ?>" />
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $errorMessage1; ?></span><br /><br />

                    Amount: &nbsp;<input ="text" name="mealTotal" value="<?php echo $mealTotal; ?>" />
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $errorMessage2; ?></span><br /><br />

                    <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" <?php echo $agreement; ?>  />
                    Do you agreement to the terms and conditions?
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $agreementError; ?></span><br /><br />


                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />  &nbsp;|&nbsp;  <input type="reset" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset!">
                </form>
```

Comment: Not enough info here, does running myFunction clear the form?

Comment: I've added the whole form portion of the from to my question above. You can see a working demo here: (school.max-o-matic.com/…) you have to scroll down to the fifth assignment which i'm currently working on. After clicking continue which commits the user entered data to string, i'd like to be able to clear it if that is possible. I'd also like it if i could get the page to load to the same position on submit so i don't have to keep scrolling down.

Comment: I just figured out how to on click, have the page scroll to where it was originally so i don't have to scroll so much by setting the action to 'action="#a050"'. So yeah for that. Still trying to figure out how to clear the user entered data.

Answer (score 3):

Reset does not clear the form, but resets the form to its default values.  If you are pre-populating the form inputs with the submitted data, those are what the form will reset to. If that's the case, to clear the form, you will need to have Javascript set all values to empty.

Comment: I'm wanting to clear the user data entered. Here is a working example of the form in action (http://school.max-o-matic.com/itc216.php?userName=dfg&mealTotal=dfd&submit=Continue). I am wanting to remove/clean the string i guess? That way when i put the next assignment in i will have a clean test state to continue on with (i know it's wacky)

Comment: If you don't want the query string in the URL, then submit the form as a POST. My response on clearing the form still holds.

Comment: Oh, I thought perhaps that pre-populating the form meant that i had html filling in an attribute verse the user filling it in. I will try to work with using POST and see how that goes. Thank your for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use event delegation

```
$('#clearbutton').on('click', function(){
    $("#myForm").reset();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I revised my script as you suggested but it didn't work as i was hoping. I"m very weak on javascript so I may not have done it correctly.

Comment: What is `$`?  The OP does not indicate he is using jQuery (or any other framework).

Comment: Nope. Not using jQuery, I don't know jQuery. I have a little php and some html and i can sort of read a javascript at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to redirect after processing the form, so that the URL is clear.

This is generally a good idea even when doing a POST, so that refreshing the page doesn't create a new entry.

I guess you aren't really processing the form yet so you don't have a way to display the entry unless it's in the URL, but that would be the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You Forgot to add the id for the form in the form add

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./itc216.php" method="get" id="myForm">
```